# Requirements for Reading Freebase .json dumps

Tags: freebase

I have a machine with Windows 7 and 8gb ram 500gb HD. I see everywhere I either have to "rent" virtual machine using AWS or have a server. My question is can I somehow work with freebase data on my machine locally. Can I some how access some topic without loading it in a database rather by parsing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Freebase data dumps are in RDF format, not JSON.  They definitely can be processed incrementally on a laptop using zgrep, cut, etc to filter things to a subset that you're interested in.  See some of my other answers to questions asked about the Freebase data dumps for example commands.

Comment: Thank you! @tommorris :)